# How can i restrict remote login in SQL Server 2012 Express using management policies

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-server

Does anyone know method to restrict remote login using management policies.

Comment: I am not sure but either I will control this from firewall side by allowing specific IP and then I would use Logon trigger. I am not sure whether policy based management would effectively do this

Comment: Can you explain with more details what are you really trying to achieve? If, for example, you are trying to stop developers logging into production servers, there are better ways.

Comment: I  want to stop developers logging into production server , moreover i also getting logs of many login attempt for user "sa" for different ip at same time. While unchecking "allow remote connections option " from server properties the site does not work properly.

Comment: You're thinking of it in the wrong way. You need to go back to basics and overhaul your security policies at both a SQL Server and Windows Server Level. Can you use Active Directory groups? Group users into appropriate areas and grant the correct rights via those groups...?

Answer (score 2):

As you explained in the comments section, the objective is to prevent developers logging into production server. There are many ways to achieve this. The first and foremost is **a company policy**.

Talk with your manager. Prepare for the meeting by making a list of reasons why access should be restricted. In addition, try to invent a number of counter-arguments and ripostes for those too. Bear in mind that developers are working for the company too, so you (the company, that is) should have development servers and whatnot so that developers can, say, develop.

If you are in agreement with management that no developer should connect to production servers, the policy must be informed to the developers. In addition, tell what resources the developers are supposed to use. If they don't know better, how would they change the ways?

Should the management decide that developer access is needed to production, *dont't* try to enforce limits by your own. This is about company property, not your personal playgroud.

If you got a policy that denies developer access, you can start erecting technical limits to enforce the policy. Start by looking at Windows authentication and Active Directory groups.